# select2 - Loading remote data - always show search field but expand with results/noResults on focus

Tags: css, jquery-select2

is it possible in Select2 to while using Loading remote data to have the search input always visible and not expanded only when clicked on the select?

The next thing would be to hide the search results (or no results, or please enter n or more character message) until the user has clicked inside the input.

And the last thing would be to put some placeholder text inside the search field.

I've been playing around with it for some time but can't figure it out.

Comment: Post some code to play with :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski It's this example: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax but I can't figure out how to make the jsfiddle work.